# What is the name of the matrix that is created by a vector times its transpose.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, terminology

I am looking for the name of the matrix created by the following operation:

$Z = z*z^T$

I know it should create a symmetric matrix with an element $Z_{ij} = z_{i}z_{j}$

Comment: That's the **outer product** of $z$ with itself: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product

Comment: You could also call it a rank-1 matrix (unless $z=0$, when the rank is zero). All rank-1 matrices can be written that way.

Comment: This is a combination of a projection and a dilation; if $z$ were a unit vector, this would simply be an orthogonal projection.  Instead, any components parallel to $z$ are dilated by a factor of $|z|^2$.

Comment: Or if $z$ has been normalized, "the projection onto $z$"

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen all **symmetric** (or Hermitian) rank-1 matrices can be written that way.  Other rank-1 matrices can be written as $uv^T$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a special case of the *tensor product of vectors* known as [outer product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product). It has some interesting properties, for example that the trace of the matrix is the square of the (Euclidean) norm of the vector. And as you point out it is always symmetric.